Remove specific data along with the angle brackets in SQL
I need to remove specific data from a SQL column along with data, I can't  get the right approach. Please help me out.
Example Input:
<div></div><div><div><div><div><p>12345</p></div></div></div></div>
<div><div><span>45678<span></span></span></div></div>
<div><div>Test No.</div></div><div><div><div><div><p>4466</p></div></div></div></div>
<div>6789</div>
<p></p><p><i>As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.</i></p>

Desired Output
12345
45678
Test No.4466
6789
As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.

Column data type is varchar NULL and I have tried the below but not working
Select Col, REPLACE(col, SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('<', col), LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE(col)) - CHARINDEX('<', col) + 2), '') 
from table

Just wondering don't we have straight code in SQL Server in order to remove <></> angle brackets and it's value and keep the rest?

Why would you undo that edit...?

Is that XML in an XML type column in your SQL Server table? Also, please show us what you have tried ...

Sorry above values are loading in Sql server in a column

Yes, and is that column an xml column, @MrD ?

Column data type is varchar NULL and I have tried the below but not working Select Col, REPLACE(col, SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('<', col), LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE(col)) - CHARINDEX('<', col) + 2), '') from table

Please post what you have tried in your original question, properly formatted and all! Do not post this into comments!

Is the real question how to strip all tags from an HTML fragment? You can't do that with SQL and can't use XML functions because that's not valid XML. Unless the full document is properly formed. SQL is a query language, not an HTML parser. T-SQL doesn't even have regular expressions, so there's no way you can strip all HTML tags

Are any of the values in oyur varchar column not valid xml, @MrD ? Does SELECT YourStringColumn FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml,YourStringColumn) IS NULL AND YourStringColumn IS NOT NULL; return any rows? If the answer is "yes" then the solution to your question is "don't use T-SQL". (And even it's it's "no", I'd still suggest that's the answer.)

It's a lot easier and faster to strip tags in a client language like C# or Python. Why do it in SQL ?

Assuming your HTML is also valid XML, you can just use the following code to get all text nodes and concatenate them together.
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.xhtml,
  t.xhtml.query('//text()').value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS value
FROM t;

.query('//text()') gets all the text nodes, you can use any XQuery filter to get whatever nodes you want. Then .value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') concats them all together.
db<>fiddle

This goes "wonky" if the value the OP has given us is a single xml value: db<>fiddle

@ThomA What's wrong about it? OP seems to want to get it all concatted together. If they want a space you can just do for $t in //text() return concat($t, " ") Note how OP's example has Test No.4466 concatted with no space.

SELECT
t.id,
t.xhtml,
t.xhtml.query('//text()').value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS value
FROM t; This code worked well for me, thanks Charlieface

If your HTML is also valid xml you could treat is a XML. One method would be to use a recursive Common Table Expression (rCTE) to just iterate through the child nodes and then return values where the value isn't NULL. There might be other methods using XQuery to do this without recursion.
DECLARE @XML varchar(3000) = '<div></div><div><div><div><div><p>12345</p></div></div></div></div>
<div><div><span>45678<span></span></span></div></div>
<div><div>Test No.</div></div><div><div><div><div><p>4466</p></div></div></div></div>
<div>6789</div>
<p></p><p><i>As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.</i></p>';

SELECT @XML AS XMLString
INTO #YourTable;


WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT X.N.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS NodeValue, --Choose an appropriate length, I just went with 50 as an arbitrary value
           X.N.query('*') AS NodeQuery
    FROM #YourTable YT
          CROSS APPLY(VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(xml,YT.XMLString)))V(XML)
          CROSS APPLY V.XML.nodes('/*') X(N)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.N.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS NodeValue, --Choose an appropriate length, I just went with 50 as an arbitrary value
           C.N.query('*') AS NodeQuery
    FROM rCTE r
         CROSS APPLY r.NodeQuery.nodes('./child::node()') C(N))
SELECT r.NodeValue
FROM rCTE r
WHERE r.NodeValue IS NOT NULL;

If your HTML isn't valid xml, then T-SQL is simply the wrong place to do this, in my opinion.

Far too complicated, you can just use a // all-descendants axis

Why I stated "There might be other methods using XQuery to do this without recursion." This is just the direction I went, @Charlieface , I didn't say it was the right one.

To be clear.  HTML is not XML.
Tired of extracting strings between two unlike delimiters, I created this function some time ago.  Perhaps this will help or dbFiddle
If in a Table
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(max))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('<div/divdivdivdivdivp>12345</p/div/div/div/divdivdivspan>45678<span/span/span/div/divdivdiv>Test No.</div/divdivdivdivdivp>4466</p/div/div/div/divdiv>6789</divp/ppi>As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.</i/p>')
 
Select B.* 
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](SomeCol,'>','</') B

If Passing a string
Declare @S varchar(max) = '<div/divdivdivdivdivp>12345</p/div/div/div/divdivdivspan>45678<span/span/span/div/divdivdiv>Test No.</div/divdivdivdivdivp>4466</p/div/div/div/divdiv>6789</divp/ppi>As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.</i/p>'

Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'>','</') B

Results
RetSeq  RetVal
1       12345
2       Test No.
3       4466
4       6789
5       As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.

The TVF if interested
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delim1,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
            Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1
)


Here is another option.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY is converting VARCHAR(3000) column into XML data type.
XQuery data() function gets all textual values, and automatically adds a space as a separator.
No need to use a recursive XPath expression "//..." for performance reasons.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, fragment VARCHAR(3000));
INSERT @tbl (fragment) VALUES
('<div></div><div><div><div><div><p>12345</p></div></div></div></div>'),
('<div><div><span>45678<span></span></span></div></div>'),
('<div><div>Test No.</div></div><div><div><div><div><p>4466</p></div></div></div></div>'),
('<div>6789</div>'),
('<p></p><p><i>As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.</i></p>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
  , TRIM(c.query('data(/*)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) AS value
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST(fragment AS XML)) AS t1(c);

Output



id
value




1
12345


2
45678


3
Test No. 4466


4
6789


5
As per the attachment, no provided because we were supposed to be onboarded.



